# 'IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseCookieAuthentication'

Tags: c#

How can I resolve that `IAppBuilder` does not contain a definition for 'UseCookieAuthentication' and the best extension method overload 'CookieAuthenticationExtensions.UseCookieAuthentication(IAppBuilder, CookieAuthenticationOptions)' requires a receiver of type 'IAppBuilder?

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
      app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager> 
                      (ApplicationUserManager.Create);

      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
   app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new 
                           PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14)            
        };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
      }
```

Comment: What is the questin, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an assembly reference to `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`, you can download it form Nuget. Then make sure to add the using as well:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have already done it. If there is any other modification
then please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are encountering, "IAppBuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseCookieAuthentication'," typically occurs when there's a mismatch between the version of the ASP.NET Identity framework you're using and the version of the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies library. The method UseCookieAuthentication might not be available in the version of the library you are using.
Try the following:

1. Update your nuget packages

   Make sure you have the latest packages for the below:

   Microsoft.Owin.Security

   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
2. If you are using a newer version of ASP.NET Identity or Owin, the method to configure cookie authentication might have changed. Ensure you are using the correct configuration. For example, with newer versions, you can use app.UseAuthentication() for configuring authentication middleware.